# Where is the alleyway?

Tags: kingdom-hearts

I know I found the alleyway by accident the first time I was in Traverse Town, but now that I need to find it in order to find the underground cavern where Leon is training, I can't find it.

I have wandered all over Traverse Town, and I can't find the entrance anywhere. This is getting frustrating!

How do I get to the alleyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is next to the fountain in the second district. If you are facing the fountain, it is on the right. There are other ways to get to it as well. For example, you can go through the house of the Dalmatians, you can go to the alley where you first started and get there that way (though that is blocked off until later in the game), or I believe there is an entrance from Merlin's cave as well, though that one will lead you directly to the cave where they are training I believe, so I'm not sure that one will be available to you yet.

Comment: What district is the fountain in?

Comment: @AshleyNunn Second District.